# Запуск приложения от имени администратора

Tags: windows, winapi, uac, delphi

Есть некоторое системное приложение, которое запускается из автозагрузки каждый раз при входе в систему Windows. Для корректной работы приложения необходимы права администратора( копирование, удаление файлов ).
Я могу получить права администратора при самом первом запуске приложения( утилита runas.exe ), приложение добавилось в автозагрузку  (в ключ `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`), но при всех последующих запусках приложения (из автозагрузки ) права администратора не получаются( с помощью все той же утилиты! ). В итоге приложение работает в корне некорректно.
Что можете посоветовать? Ведь всякие там браузеры могут обходить UAC для обновления своих плагинов, например. Как им это удается?

Желательно без служб, так как приложение сильно разрослось и переписывать его нельзя.

---

Как вы поступаете, если ваши приложения не могут работать без наивысших прав?

Answer (score 2):

Если есть возможность, то реализуйте некоторое системное приложение как службу Windows - тогда оно будет запускаться под аккаунтом SYSTEM или LOCAL SERVICE (или другим системным, точно не помню). Почитайте тему службы Win.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу!